# AngularJS: On click show new extra row and hide all others extra rows?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html table, `<tbody>` of it is generated with angular `ng-repeat`. Here is my html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="car in carList | filter:tableFilter" ng-click="activeRow = car.name">
        <td><a target="_blank" href="{{car.carLink}}">{{car.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{car.review}}</td>
        <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
        <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
        <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
        <td>{{car.price}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="activeRow==car.name">
        <td>{{car.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to do so when you click on the row, new row is showing up, but when you click on another row I need the first one to hide.

Here is table in browser with an active row:

[image]

I have tried to do this with `ng-show` like this:

```
ng-show="activeRow==car.name"
```

`activeRow` is  a `$scope` variable inside of my controller. The problem is, that new row is showing up, but not hiding when you click on another.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Try to encapsulate the `activeRow` property inside an object, like `$scope.model = { activeRow: 'someValue' };` and then on the HTML `ng-show="model.activeRow==car.name"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ng-repeat` directive creates a new scope and the `activeRow` property is on the parent's controller scope, you will have to encapsulate that property inside an object. This way scope's prototypal inheritance will work as expected.

On the controller:

```
$scope.model = { activeRow: 'someValue' };
```

And on the HTML:

```
ng-show="model.activeRow == car.name"
```

More info on prototypal inheritance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482).

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide a namespace for your `activeRow` variable because ng-repeat has its own scope.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="car in carList | filter:tableFilter" ng-click="main.activeRow = car.name">
            <td><a target="_blank" href="{{car.carLink}}">{{car.name}}</a></td>
            <td>{{car.review}}</td>
            <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
            <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
            <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
            <td>{{car.price}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="main.activeRow==car.name">
            <td colspan="6">{{car.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Working demo using the ["controller as"](http://codetunnel.com/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/) technique: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/KAmFB

This technique is functionally identical to doing this in your controller:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.main = this;
    this.activeRow = "Lightning McQueen";
});
```

Angular allows the "as" syntax in ng-controller definitions as a simple shortcut for creating a namespace on your scope that refers to the controller function's execution context (`this`). It's a nice way to create a namespace without having to create a random meaningless object such as `$scope.model = { ... };`.